# For item in data

Tags: javascript

Редко работаю с JS, но вот пришлось и неожиданно для себя обнаружил очень странное (на мой взгляд) поведение стандартных циклов. Т.е. я пишу например `for (let index in data)`, но в большинстве языков параметром цикла идет сам элемент, а не его ключ... Я даже ненадолго залип на этой ошибке прежде чем понял что там именно ключ передается. А можно как то сделать чтобы возвращался и элемент тоже? Или только самому писать `let item = data[index]`? Ну типа чтобы может какой-нибудь кортеж возвращался если они тут есть... Или еще что-то.

Например как в питоне: `for key, value in data.iteritems():`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последних версиях языка ввели [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for (let i of arr) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Кроме этого можно использовать методы [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) и [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (данные методы можно применять к любым объектам, не только к массивам)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.entries(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(arr)));
```

> Например как в питоне: `for key, value in data.iteritems():`

Можно использовать [деструктуризацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) при обходе:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте `for ... of ...`

```
for (let value of data) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Обратите внимание на поддержку браузеров!

IE не поддерживает данную конструкцию.

Comment: Отлично! А если мне все-таки понадобится и ключ элемента? Я могу получить вариант цикла с ключом и элементом? Или только использовать калбэки вроде array.forEach()?